# Is the infinite list capacity built into the `Ord` typeclass, or a product of haskell's definition of a number?

Tags: haskell, lazy-evaluation, recursive-datastructures

I'm trying to wrap my head around how haskell achieves infinite lists... here's my road block:

You have a list of type `A`, and `A` implements the `Ord` typeclass. You can describe a span of ordered elements like so (intergers, for example):

```
[1..6]
```

which equates to...

```
Cons 1 (Cons 2 (Cons 3 (Cons 4 (Cons 5 (Cons 6 (Empty))))))
```

How would haskell know how to construct an infinite list? Would haskell be able to create an infinite list of any datatype that supports `Ord`?

Comment: Also, the definition of an interger in haskell has a limit. Is the theoretical infinite value of a number defined in the `Num` typeclass recursively or something?? Any help would be awesome!!!

Comment: The trick is essentially to only create bits of the infinite list as they are used. It's called lazy evaluation, which is worth looking up.

Comment: Oh, and while `Int` is machine representation limited, `Integer` is capable of being unboundedly large (well, eventually it'll be so large you run out of all system memory). Finally, things in the `Num` typeclass may be finite or infinite—they don't have to be regular numbers! Just things you can sensibly add/subtract/multiply/divide (essentially, kind-of Rings, if you want to explore much more deeply).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It might be a little easier to get away from the syntactic-sugary `[a..b]` stuff, and think about a simple function from the Prelude:

```
repeat :: a -> [a]
repeat x = x : repeat x
```

You should forget about evaluation for now and start thinking declaratively, i.e. think of the above like a function in mathematics which can be read:

> "repeat x" means "x" consed with "repeat x"

Yes, "lazy evaluation" is what we call what allows us to express this, but ideally we'd really like to just forget about evaluation and think about what our code *means*. In imperative programming you are obligated to think about evaluation at all times.

Here is more or less what your `[1..]` desugars to:

```
enumFrom n = n : enumFrom (succ n)
```

and you can see in @tel's answer how the compiler goes about expanding that.

Comment: Aha!! So is `repeat` a typeclass then? And is `..` a function that relies on the `repeat` constraint?

Comment: @AthanClark No, repeat is just an ordinary function that works on any value to create a list. The .. isn't a function; it's what we call syntactic sugar - so that [1..] is a sweeter way of writing something that the compiler will turn into enumFrom 1.

Comment: Ahh yeah I think I understand it now. I wish that the haskell report would fully support custom syntax like "[,]". Thank you for your help though!

Comment: @AthanClark ah sorry, I just used `repeat` because I thought it would be a slightly simpler example of the same idea w/r/t lazy infinite lists

Answer (score 6):

Haskell "creates" infinite lists because it doesn't create any elements until it needs to. For instance, let's walk through an expansion of `head [1..]` which results in `1` in Haskell and an infinite loop in strict languages.

```
head [1..]

===                                 [expand `head`, literally 
                                     just inline the definition]
case [1..] of
  []        -> error "empty list"
  (x : xs)  -> x

===                                 [evaluate [1..] one step,
                                     check if it matches the case]
case 1:[2..] of
  []        -> error "empty list"
  (x : xs)  -> x

===                                 [it does!]

(1 : [2..]) -> 1

===                                 [fin]

1
```

Note that this is pretty backward compared to most languages which would start by attacking the definition of `[1..]` instead of attacking `head`.

You can write `[x..]` not for any type in the `Ord` typeclass (which only lets us say whether two things are greater or lesser than one another) but instead for anything in the `Enum` typeclass as `[x..]` translates to `enumFrom x` where `enumFrom :: Enum a => a -> [a]`.

Comment: Thanks!! So would that make `..` a value constructor, or a function similar to `fix`?

Comment: Neither, it's pure syntax sugar. `[x..]` is just translated from `enumFrom x` and `enumFrom x = x : enumFrom (succ x)`

Comment: is '[', '..', and ']' newtypes or something then? How is it sugared in haskell?
Also, would that mean that `Int` has a really basic implementation of `Enum` and `Interger` would have a really complex implementation?

Comment: `[`, `..`, and `]` don't really have a sensible way of being talked about in Haskell terminology in the same way that `do` and `<-` don't. Int has a reasonably simple `Enum` implementation---it just falls back on a 32 or 64 bit machine integer. `Integer` falls back on [a BigInteger library](http://gmplib.org/).

Answer (score 0):

The concept of infinite lists should be easy to understand for anyone coming from an object-oriented background.

The trick is to think about Haskell lists not as arrays or even linked lists, but as iterator objects. An iterator object is an object that has two methods, `hasNext` and `getNext`.

Normally, an iterator's `hasNext` would return `False` after a finite number of `getNext` invocations. That is certainly true if you consider iterators tied to "real" collections such as arrays, hash maps, files etc.

But nothing inherently forces an iterator to be "finite". You could implement an infinite iterator very easily. In Haskell-like pseudocode:

```
object Iterator where
  hasNext _ = True
  getNext = do
    state <- get
    put (state + 1)
    return state
```

If you didn't know how this iterator is actually implemented, just by observing its behaviour you'd think that it's tied to an infinite (or at least very huge) collection. But it is just that — an object that returns consecutive numbers.

Another similar analogy is special files in UNIX, such as `/dev/zero` or `/dev/random`. If they were tied to real files on your hard disk, the disk would have to be infinite. But they are not — instead the contents is generated on demand by the kernel, and you can demand as much of it as you like.

Haskell's lazy lists work exactly like that, except they also "buffer" all the produced values, so that you can examine them repeatedly without doing repeated evaluation.

Comment: Sorry man, I was more concerned with how "infinite" could be implemented in your own recursive datastructire. Is there an `infinite` or `repeat` typeclass that my datatype could implement? I've got the idea for how I could use it, I'd just like to know how I could _make_ it haha.

Comment: Ok, sorry if this wasn't helpful. It was clear from the question that you misunderstand how infinite lists work, but maybe I didn't guess which part exactly you misunderstand. Anyway, I'm glad you got the answer you were looking for.